# Is it possible to upload/choose the file from sharepoint location to application using HTML5 file upload?

Tags: html, file, sharepoint, file-upload

I would like to open/select the file from **SharePoint location**, the file dialogue box(HTML file upload feature) should open with a list of files from the SharePoint directory instead of pointing to the system directory. is it possible?

Currently, the dialogue box opens with the current system directory file location.

Is it feasible with all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is feasible. 
However, you might need to custom design the interface.
You would need to perform a rest API call to SharePoint document library to show the list of files. You can use Microsoft Graph API to make the calls and extract the details.